# Zoom controls on text view?

Tags: android, textview, zooming

Hi guys,

I need a small help regarding the textview,when  i have tapped on the textview it need to be zoom(IN) else it should be Zoom(OUT).can any help regarding this.

Thanks,
Nikhilreddy.

Comment: hi have u done with zooming funtionality of textview in android...i am also searching for this same..can u help me out ..vv thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think zooming the text view will be achieved by Scaling property. I am not sure but it may help you.

I think you have to use Gesture Detector to catch the zoom-in or zoom-out actions.

One thing you have to clarify is while zooming the text view, other views should not disturb or may happen ?